# VBA: Nested For/Loop

Tags: vba, for-loop

I am creating a macro that will copy all data from one workbook/multiple sheets into another workbook/multiple sheets.  The first spreadsheet has 7 worksheets named as Sun-Sat.  The second worksheet has 10 worksheets 3 worksheets are irrelevant and the other 7 worksheets are named Sunday-Saturday.

I tested each for loop separately and they work as needed.  When trying to combine them the inner for statement repeats and cycles through all dates before backing out.  I have tried incorporating a exit for to jump out of the inner for but when going back to the inner for it does not increment +1 to go to the next date.  Is there a simple way to add +1 from the outer for statement?

```
enter code here
Dim wsShortDays, wsFullDays As Variant
Dim wsShortDaysCrnt, wsFullDaysCrnt As Long
Dim SD, FD As Long

wsShortDays = Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat")
wsFullDays = Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")

For FD = LBound(wsFullDays) To UBound(wsFullDays)
    With wbk1.Worksheets(wsFullDays(FD))

        For SD = LBound(wsShortDays) To UBound(wsShortDays)
            With wbk2.Worksheets(wsShortDays(SD))
                wbk2.Worksheets(wsShortDays(SD)).Activate
                Range("A:H").Copy
            End With
            Exit For
        Next SD


        wbk1.Worksheets(wsFullDays(FD)).Activate
        Range("C:J").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
        SD = 1
    End With
Next FD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the inner loop as your arrays are synced just use the same reference number from the first loop.  It will equate `Sunday` with `Sun` and so forth:

```
Dim wsShortDays As Variant, wsFullDays As Variant
Dim FD As Long

wsShortDays = Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat")
wsFullDays = Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")

For FD = LBound(wsFullDays) To UBound(wsFullDays)
   wbk2.Worksheets(wsShortDays(FD)).Range("A:H").Copy
   wbk1.Worksheets(wsFullDays(FD)).Range("C:J").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
Next FD
```

Comment: you beat me to it! I had an explanation with mine also saying that excel isn't capable of stand-alone multi-threading which is why his nested for statements felt counter-intuitive to him. Our codes are 1:1 identical though.

Comment: Thanks Scott - I was really overcomplicating it!